# UrlRewrite.net optional / and optional additional url parts

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I'm writing a URL rewriter.net rule and one thing is missing.

This is the rule, and it works fine.

But i want it to work for the following situations as well:

/webshop/products/(.+)/(.+)  (with no trailing slash)

/webshop/products/(.+)/(.+)/test/bla/bla/ (with some more url parts after the parts i'm looking for)

What would be the ideal / most flexible rule to have these situations covered?